# Responsive menu on Joomla site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, menu

At the moment on my Joomla site the website goes from a normal menu to a responsive menu when the screen size width is 979px or less. I would like to set it to 1025px so I can get the responsive menu on ipads in landscape mode.

I use this template: http://demo.joomshaper.com/2013/maxima/

I know that the template is build on the helix 2 framework which uses bootstrap for handling of the menu.

Hope this was information enough, otherwise just ask.

Comment: Yes you can use media queries...set like this @media screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
    .menu {
        background-color: red;
    }
} like this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove any statements that are not constructive. You do not have to include some signature in your question, the author is shown by SO below the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the template uses Bootstrap. If you have only compiled CSS, your only option is to change / override the media-query statements; you may have to change that in several places.

If you have access to the LESS file, then you should look for LESS variables `@screen-sm`, `@screen-md`, `@screen-lg`.

BTW I think you can probably get better support from the template developers themselves

Comment: the bootstrap css, js and so on is under plugins/system/helix/ css or js and the variables.less you mentioned is under the template folder/less, but when i change it nothing seems to happen. here i have changed the values: http://i.imgur.com/HT1RoRF.png

Comment: Check if the modification dates for the CSS files have changed. If not, it means the LESS file is not automatically compiled so you have to do that yourself.

Comment: In the Joomla template manager you can edit the LESS and then click the Compile button.

Comment: i have compiled the less from the template manager: http://i.imgur.com/iUX2Som.png but it still doesnt seem to work and it seems like the template.css and variables.css in my template folder have changed by looking at the date

Comment: Ok, so the CSS date has changed. And if you open the CSS, are they ok, i.e. do they contain the modified value for breakpoint? And you are making sure your browser cache has been cleared? If so, then it's back to "ask template developers for help". You are doing the right things and maybe the template works differently then we suppose.

Comment: the css does change but doesnt affect the menu. but when i change this file: \plugins\system\helix\css\bootstrap-responsive.min.css it kind of works. i change the @media max-width from 979, 980 to 1024, 1025, and it shows the responsive menu instead of the normal menu, but it is open from screen-width 979 px to 1024 px and you cant close it.

Comment: @MichaelKirkegaard I am sorry but the trouble seems to be very specific to that template so I don't have any more answers for you :-)